# Initializing objects from within Concordion test spec

Tags: testing, concordion

I am wanting to use Concordion to write tests for a simple bankAccount pgm that is offered as part of a cucumber tutorial. I am having trouble working out how to initialize objects from the concordion test spec.

I created a method in the fixture called createAccount that took an initialBalance and account number as parameters.

I call it from the test spec with ...

```
<b concordion:execute="createAccount(#accountNum,#initBalance)">
```

but when I run the test I get an error ....

java.lang.Exception: Method createAccount should have no parameters.

I know that I can just assign values to these variables from within the fixture class but think it would be a lot more useful if I could do this from the test specification.

Below is part of my test fixture with the call to createAccount

```
@RunWith(ConcordionRunner.class)
public class CashMachineTest {

    private Account newAccount;
    int initBalance = 123;
    int accountNum = 1;

    @Before
    public void createAccount(int accountNum, int initBalance) throws     Throwable{
        newAccount = new Account(accountNum, initBalance);
    }

    public int getBalance(){
        return newAccount.getBalance();
    }

    public void deposit(int amount){
        newAccount.deposit(amount);
    }
```

....

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to call the initialization method from your Concordion specification, you don't need the @Before annotation. This is used by JUnit to call methods before the execution of the actual test method. But Concordion does not run a single test method, but calls the methods in your fixture class based on your instrumentation in your specification document.

Pleas, try to remove the @Before annotation and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've made this change to my code and it's now working.